# Skip image confirmation after taking photo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm creating an app with react native that can take photos and always **after taking a photo**, the app asks if I want to accept (v) or discard (x) the photo.

[image: after take a photo]

is there any way to skip this step? 
When you take the picture already "accept" automatically.

My code:

```
_takePhoto = async () => {
    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: false
    });

    this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
};

_handleImagePicked = async pickerResult => {
    this.setState({ image: pickerResult.uri });
    //...
    this.setState({ text: 'valid' });
};
```

I searched the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker) but did not succeed.

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.54.0
- ImagePicker from 'expo'

Comment: You could use the Camera API directly, which would let you achieve this if you built your own UI around it: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera